# How to use Session in SELECT FROM

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm confused right now.

I've been coding for some while now, to fix a problem, but I'm going blind on how to do, can anyone help me?

First, I have an datatable with all my customers in, then I click "USE" I should go to another page where I can make an case. This is all good, if I only should use one table, but in my project I need more then 1 table, so my question is:

```
$sql = "SELECT customers.cust_id, 
customers.customer_name, numberplate.car 
FROM customers , numberplate WHERE SESSION = numberplate.cust_id";
```

But I can't see how to do it, I know how to make a profilepage and so on, but this ting really tricks my brian right now. Anyone to help?

My session look like this:

```
     if (isset($_GET['cust_id']) && $_GET['cust_id'] != "") {
 $id = $_GET['cust_id'];
 } else {
 $cust_id = $_SESSION['cust_id'];
 }
```

Comment: Use a `join` and a `where` clause to filter the data. The `join` should have a `on` after that relates the two tables.

Comment: Reading material: [W3 SQL Alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: @Alex What do aliases have to do with this question?

Comment: @user3783243 nothing at this stage, I got more focused on his SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing your SQL with PHP.

$_SESSION is the variable which contains PHP's session data.
but your MYSQL statement: "WHERE SESSION = numberplate..." is referencing a column in the mysql table.

You want to use sql like:

```
SELECT customers.cust_id, 
customers.customer_name, numberplate.car 
FROM customers , numberplate WHERE numberplate.cust_id = ?";
```

and then bind the value of $_SESSION['cust_id'] to the database call.

But additionally, you're trying to JOIN two tables together without any details on how to do that...

so your SQL then becomes:

```
SELECT customers.cust_id, customers.customer_name, 
numberplate.car 
FROM customers,
JOIN numberplate ON customers.cust_id = numberplate.cust_id
WHERE numberplate.cust_id = ?
```

Comment: Okay, now I change the SELECT linie, what more do I have to do before it's only the customer 300200100's numberplates is showing from the databasse?

Comment: The WHERE statement controls which rows come out of the database, based upon the cust_id. If you want to filter on the numberplat too, you'll add an additional statement in the WHERE section, ie. "AND numberplate.reg = '300200100'" or similar.

Comment: No basicly i want to show anything from multiple tablets with the same uniqe number, in This case I have a Truck company with 300200100 as the customer ID in my database, and I wont to show anything information in All my databases with This id 300200100.

Comment: Okay... But that's a different question to what you've asked above :)